# extract data from string in lua - SubStrings and Numbers

Tags: lua

I'm trying to phrase a string for a hobby project and I'm self taught from code snips from this site and having a hard time working out this problem. I hope you guys can help.

I have a large string, containing many lines, and each line has a certain format.

I can get each line in the string using this code...

```
for line in string.gmatch(deckData,'[^\r\n]+') do
    print(line) end
```

Each line looks something like this...

> 3x  Rivendell Minstrel (The Hunt for Gollum)

What I am trying to do is make a table that looks something like this for the above line.

```
table = {}
  table['The Hunt for Gollum'].card = 'Rivendell Minstrel'
  table['The Hunt for Gollum'].count = 3
```

So my thinking was to extract everything inside the parentheses, then extract the numeric vale. Then delete the first 4 chars in the line, as it will always be '1x ', '2x ' or '3x '

I have tried a bunch of things.. like this...

```
word=str:match("%((%a+)%)")
```

but it errors if there are spaces...

my test code looks like this at the moment...

```
line = '3x  Rivendell Minstrel (The Hunt for Gollum)'
    num = line:gsub('%D+', '')
    print(num) -- Prints "3"

card2Fetch = string.sub(line, 5)
    print(card2Fetch) -- Prints "Rivendell Minstrel (The Hunt for Gollum)"

key = string.gsub(card2Fetch, "%s+", "") -- Remove all Spaces
    key=key:match("%((%a+)%)") -- Fetch between ()s
    print(key) -- Prints "TheHuntforGollum"
```

Any ideas how to get the "The Hunt for Gollum" text out of there including the spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a single pattern capturing all fields:

```
x,y,z=line:match("(%d+)x%s+(.-)%s+%((.*)%)")
t = {}
t[z] = {}
t[z].card = y
t[z].count = x
```

The pattern reads: capture a run of digits before `x`, skip whitespace, capture everything until whitespace followed by open parenthesis, and finally capture everything until a close parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you this code works really well, as it returns nil, if the string doesn't match the format. So a simple nil test can remove junk data in the text file and we only get the good stuff GREAT.. you wouldn't happen to know how to modify the code to snatch a line that dose not have the numbers as well... so like "Frodo Baggins (Conflict at the Carrock)" these lines also return nil errors.. but I also need them.

Comment: @aJynks, try another match if the first fails: `y,z=line:match("^%s*(.-)%s+%((.*)%)")`.